# Android - receive messages from server using socket io

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I am developing an android application using Socket.IO-Java-Client by Gottox (AndroidAsync by koush as well). I have no problems connecting to the socket or sending messages over the socket, but I am not receiving messages or responses from the socket.

The activity starts off receiving a list of messages through an API, and then opens a socket to send and receive outgoing/incoming messages. Any new messages appear if I restart the activity, but this is through the API - I need to receive them from the socket while the activity is still open.

Here is my socket-related code:

```
public final void openSocket() {
    try {
        socket = new SocketIO(SERVER_URL);
        socket.connect(this);
        join();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void join() {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.putOpt("join", mChat.getID());
        socket.emit("join", this, json);
        // socket.emit("join", json);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Send: " + content.getTextWithEmojis());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json = prepareJSONObject(json);
        // socket.emit("send", this, json);
        socket.emit("send", json);
        content.setText("");
        addChat(json);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addChat(JSONObject jObject) {
    ChatPost post;
    try {
        post = parseJSONObject(jObject);
        mChatMessages.add(Arrays.asList(new ChatPost[] {post}));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Server said:" + json.toString());

        if(json.has("args")) {
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("args");
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

            ChatPost post;
            post = parseJSONObject(jObject);
            mChatMessages.add(Arrays.asList(new ChatPost[] {post}));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Server said: " + data);
}

@Override
public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
    Log.i(TAG, "an Error occured");
    socketIOException.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection terminated.");
}

@Override
public void onConnect() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection established");
}

@Override
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    if (args.length > 0)
        Log.i(TAG, "Args '" + args[0].toString() + "'");
    for (Object arg : args)
        Log.i(TAG, "Args '" + arg.toString() + "'");
}
```

Log:

```
I/io.socket(9753): > 5:::{"args":[{"join":"101"}],"name":"join"}
I/io.socket(9753): < 1::
I/io.socket(9753): < 5:::{"name":"ready"}
I/io.socket(9753): < 2::
I/io.socket(9753): < 2::
I/io.socket(9753): > 2::
I/io.socket(9753): > 2::
I/io.socket(9753): > 5:::{"args":[{"content":"test","chat_id":"101","user_id":"5"}],"name":"send"}
I/io.socket(9753): < 2::
I/io.socket(9753): > 2::
```

I receive a response for "join", but not for "send." Am I missing something?

EDIT: I tried using AndroidAsync by koush, but encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, turned out to be a backend issue